# Why does casting an ArrayList 's generic to a superclass not work?

Tags: java, generics, casting

Can someone please explain to me why the line marked `//this line gives a compile error (why?)` in the following code sample does not work?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class GenericCastCheck {

    class A{
    }

    class B extends A{
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        A aObject = new A();
        B bObject = new B();

        //this line works fine
        aObject = bObject;
        //this line gives a compile (expected)
        bObject = aObject;

        ArrayList<A> aList = new ArrayList<A>();
        ArrayList<B> bList = new ArrayList<B>();

        //this line gives a compile error (why?)
        aList = bList;
        //this line gives a compile error (expected)
        bList = aList;
    }
}
```

Specifically, when we say that `bList` is of type `ArrayList<B>`, does it not mean that each element of it is an instance of `B`? If so, then what is the problem in casting it to `ArrayList<A>`, if we can cast individual instances of `B` to `A`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is this:

```
ArrayList<A> aList = new ArrayList<A>();
ArrayList<B> bList = new ArrayList<B>();
aList = bList; // if this were valid...
aList.add(new A()); // ...what should happen here?
B b = bList.get(0); // ...and here?
```

If you do the same thing with arrays, you get an ArrayStoreException in line 4 at runtime. For generic collections, it was decided to prevent that kind of thing at compile time.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I realized that I should use `aList = new ArrayList<A>( bList);` instead of `aList = bList`, which compiles well too. :)

Answer (score 6):

Because generic are strict. they aren't covarient

`ArrayList<A>` aList can only refer to an `ArrayList` of type `A`

---

From [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29)

> Unlike arrays, generic classes are
>   neither covariant nor contravariant.
>   For example, neither `List<String>` nor
>   `List<Object>` is a subtype of the
>   other:
>
> ```
> // a is a single-element List of String
> List<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();
> a.add("foo");
>
> // b is a List of Object
> List<Object> b = a; // This is a compile-time error
> ```
>
> However, generic type parameters can
>   contain wildcards (a shortcut for an
>   extra type parameter that is only used
>   once). Example: Given a requirement
>   for a method which operates on Lists,
>   of any object, then the only
>   operations that can be performed on
>   the object are those for which the
>   type relationships can be guaranteed
>   to be safe.
>
> ```
> // a is a single-element List of String
> List<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();
> a.add("foo");
>
> // b is a List of anything
> List<?> b = a;
>
> // retrieve the first element
> Object c = b.get(0);
> // This is legal, because we can guarantee
> // that the return type "?" is a subtype of Object
>
> // Add an Integer to b.
> b.add(new Integer (1)); 
> // This is a compile-time error; 
> // we cannot guarantee that Integer is
> // a subtype of the parameter type "?"
> ```
>
> Wildcards can also be bound, e.g. "`?
>   extends Foo`" or "`? super Foo`" for
>   upper and lower bounds, respectively.
>   This allows to refine permitted
>   performance. Example: given a `List<?
>   extends Foo>`, then an element can be
>   retrieved and safely assigned to a `Foo`
>   type (covariance). Given a `List<?
>   super Foo>`, then a `Foo` object can be
>   safely added as an element
>   (contravariance).

Answer (score 0):

Animesh,

Even though class B is subtype of A, ArrayList< B > is not a subtype of ArrayList < A >. Its on the same line as in B[] is not subtype of A[]. These are two independent unrelated types.

Answer (score 0):

Because there is *no* subtype relation in Java between `C<A>` and `C<B>`, even if `A` is a supertype of `B` or vice versa.

If your interested in the details lookup co- / contra-variance in Wikipedia.

Note, that in Java arrays are co-variant, which means `A[]` is a supertype of `B[]` if `A` is a supertype of `B`. That is the reason why you sometimes get strange cast exception with arrays.