# Why is casting a sub-classed collection of subclassed objects to its superclass collection of superclass objects not allowed in java?

Tags: java, generics

The code is also at https://github.com/timp21337/java-generics-example

```
package a;

import java.util.List;

public interface Container<T> {
  List<T> getThings();
}

public class ContainerContainer {
  public Container<Thing> getThingContainer() {
    return new ThingContainer<Thing>();
  }
}

public class ThingContainer<T extends a.Thing> implements Container<T> {
  @Override
  public List<T> getThings() {
    return null;
  }
}

public class Thing {
}
```

Package b

```
package b;
import java.util.List;

public class ContainerContainer extends a.ContainerContainer {
  ThingContainer<Thing> thingContainer = new ThingContainer<Thing>();
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  public a.Container<a.Thing> getContainer() {
    return (a.Container<a.Thing>)(Object)thingContainer; //YUCK
  }
}

public class ThingContainer<T extends a.Thing> 
     implements a.Container<T> {
  @Override
  public List<T> getThings() {
    return null;
  }
}

public class Thing extends a.Thing {
}
```

My question is why do I have to coerce the b.ThingContainer (marked YUCK above) when it is a subclass of a.ThingContainer and the Things it contains are subclasses of a.Thing?

Comment: I think this answers your question. http://stackoverflow.com/q/6044329/422353

Comment: +1 for a well-written question; -1 for not searching for an answer first; net: 0

Comment: Thanks @madth3, yes particularly the link to <http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29>

Comment: Thanks @Jim-Garrison, I did search but the answers I found were to the opposite problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's consider a much simpler example, to remove all the irrelevant details. (Here, instead of `b.Thing` we will use `String`, and instead of `a.Thing` we will use `Object`; `String` is a subclass of `Object`, so it is analogous. Instead of `a.Container`, we will use `List`. The subclassing of the container is irrelevant, as you will see.) If you can understand why this example doesn't work, you will understand your problem.

```
List<String> foo = new ArrayList<String>();
List<Object> bar = foo; // why doesn't this work?
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not sure that someone without experience would understand your example better with just those two lines of code.

Comment: Because bar could now accept Integers which could be mistakenly accessed via foo. Thanks @newacct